# Right clicking on hyperlink in chrome always behaves like left click (/open)

Tags: google-chrome, contextual-menu

Although right click in chrome is *generally* working - as shown in screenshot - it does *not* (with any kind of reliability at least..) on links.

[image]

Instead when right clicking on a link it just opens .. the same behavior as left clicking.

I really want the context menu to come up instead - in particular to use the `Save As` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:  `Disable the Chrome PDF Viewer plugin`

[image]

Now this is not a *perfect* solution - since it would be convenient to allow that plugin to run .. but I'll take it. This is a time savings.